# How can we control Telegram Bot color text via Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Can we format a colour text message and sendFormattedMessage?

Using JavaScript + Google Web Apps to interact with Telegram Bot.

```
function sendFormattedMessage( chat_id, text, parse_mode, disable_web_page_preview,     disable_notification ) {
    var encodedText = encodeURIComponent(text);
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(vUrlTelegram + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chat_id + "&text=" + encodedText + "&parse_mode=" + parse_mode );
//  Logger.log(response.getContentText());  
}



function telegramBotMachine( id, chat_id, text, name ) {
  var sUpperText = text.toUpperCase();

  if ( sUpperText.substr( 0, 4 ) === "MENU" ) {
sendFormattedMessage( chat_id, menu(), "HTML", "false", "false" );
```

---

have obtained Telegram Bot API docs, unable to find a HTML tag to colour format a text?

Any work around?

HTML style

To use this mode, pass HTML in the parse_mode field. The following tags are currently supported:

```
<b>bold</b>, <strong>bold</strong>
<i>italic</i>, <em>italic</em>
<u>underline</u>, <ins>underline</ins>
<s>strikethrough</s>, <strike>strikethrough</strike>, <del>strikethrough</del>
<b>bold <i>italic bold <s>italic bold strikethrough</s> <u>underline italic bold</u></i> bold</b>
<a href="http://www.example.com/">inline URL</a>
<a href="tg://user?id=123456789">inline mention of a user</a>
<code>inline fixed-width code</code>
<pre>pre-formatted fixed-width code block</pre>
<pre><code class="language-python">pre-formatted fixed-width code block written in the Python programming language</code></pre>
```

Comment: It's not possible to style your texts with colors in Telegram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is still relevant for you, but they have an API method to enable htmlMode.

For instance in java it will be:

```
message.enableHtml(true);
```

And you can wrap your message with html tags and css styles.

```
String message_text = "<b>" + update.getMessage().getFrom().getFirstName() + "</b>" + " Said what? \n" + update.getMessage().getText();
```

Comment: according to telegram bot api doco, not possible to embed html tags. i will use normal and bold until telegram documents the usage of colour font, thanks anyway